# I want to edit and update document using react and pouchdb

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react and pouchdb and have started saving document. I'm also retrieving document on a simple table. But I'm looking for the best way possible to edit and update the document in pouchdb.

Here's my code for saving the record from the form:

```
submitInfo (event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    let schoolData = Object.assign({}, this.props.doc)

    if (!schoolData._id) {
      schoolData._id = schoolData.id
    }

    console.log('About to post to pouch...', schoolData._id)

    // Save to pouchdb
    this.regDb.put(schoolData, (err, result) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Successfully posted to pouchdb!')
        this.props.clearDoc()
      } else {
        console.log('Error saving to pouch...')
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
  }

return (
      <div className='form'>
        <form action='' onSubmit={this.submitInfo}>
          <div className='form__container'>
          <RegistrationInfo {...doc.RegistrationInfo} />
          <button className='button expanded' type='submit'>Save</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
```

Here's my code for retrieving the docs:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {docs: []}
    this.regDb = this.props.regDb
  }

componentDidMount () {
    this.GetDocs ()
    this.regDb.changes({
      since: 'now',
      live: true
    }).on('change', (change) => {
      this.GetDocs ()
    }).on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
  }

  GetDocs () {
    this.regDb.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then((res) => {
      var docs = res.rows.map((row) => row.doc)
      this.setState({docs})
    })
  }
```

The table:

```
return (
      <div >
        <div >
        </div>
        <div className='table-list'>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Registration Type</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Middle Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              {this.state.docs.map((doc) => <Data key={doc._id} doc={doc} {...this.props} />)}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
```

The Data:

```
class Data extends React.Component {
  render () {
    let {doc} = this.props

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{doc.RegistrationInfo['registrationtype']}</td>
        <td>{doc.RegistrationInfo['firstname']}</td>
        <td>{doc.RegistrationInfo['middlename']}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I edit and update docs on the table?

Comment: What is currently working for you, and where is your exact problem? From your code I can guess that the table is rendered correctly. You also have a working form. But it seems you cannot connect both of them.

Are you willing to introduce a routing library such as React Router or a library for state management like Redux (and Redux Form)? I would use those, but if you are not experienced with them, be warned: this is a huge complexity step. If you want to use plain react, I can also guide you, but you will need some manual state management code in any case.

Comment: @BernhardGschwantner, Whatever way is best will be good for me. I want to be able to click the table row and have the details of that doc populated on the form for editing and saving. My problem is how can I edit the record and save it. As of now, I'm not familiar with react redux, maybe you could introduce that to me if you think it's better way to go.

Comment: For Redux, best watch the author's free video course on Egghead: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Answer (score 0):

Without redux and a router, you can add your form component (You didn't post the name, so I assume it's called `YourFormComponent`) before the table:

```
return (
  <div>
    <div>
      {this.state.editId && <YourFormComponent data={this.state.docs[this.state.editId]} />
    </div>
    <div className='table-list'>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Registration Type</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Middle Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          {this.state.docs.map((doc) => <Data key={doc._id} doc={doc} {...this.props} onEdit={() => this.setState({editId: doc._id})}/>)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

In you form component, prefill the input fields with the values from `this.props.data`.

In the Data component, make sure call the onEdit function when clicking the edit button:

```
class Data extends React.Component {
  render () {
    let {doc, onEdit} = this.props

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{doc.RegistrationInfo['registrationtype']}</td>
        <td>{doc.RegistrationInfo['firstname']}</td>
        <td>
          {doc.RegistrationInfo['middlename']}
          <button onClick={onEdit}>Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

Also make sure you set the editId to undefined in your submitInfo function.

This code is a bit simple and fragile (and doesn't follow best practices), but you should get the idea: You need a button to edit a row, an action that reacts and sets the state to the doc._id to edit when the edit button is clicked, and a component to render the form whenever that id is set.

Hope that helped!